# Keep jQuery accordion state on postback with PHP

Tags: php, jquery-ui, accordion, state

I am using jQuery UI's accordion as a subnav on a site I am building. The problem is that I haven't been able to find a good way to maintain state between pages. I'm wondering what the best way to do this is.

I've thought of storing the index of the accordion in the database, but that seems overly complicated for a problem like this. Is there a better way? Obviously cookies and session but that is equally complicated for just a subnav...any ideas?

EDIT: Here's my code

```
$.post(
    accordion_ajax.ajaxurl,
    {
        type   : 'GET',
        action : 'accordion_ajax'
    },
    function(data){
        $(".accordion-main").accordion('option', 'collapsible', true);  
        $(".accordion-main").accordion('option', 'active', 0);
        // the accordion just does not work inside this ajax call, but if I put it outside the ajax call it works fine. Any thoughts?   
    }
);

$(".accordion-main").accordion({
    change: function(event, ui){
        $.post(
            accordion_ajax.ajaxurl,
            {
                type   : 'SET',
                action : 'accordion_ajax',
                data   : $(".accordion-main").accordion('option', 'active')

            }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't the hidden fields have to be inside form tags and submitted with a submit button in order for the data to be posted back?

Comment: Because I've tried that, but I've found no other way to postback the data unless I click a submit button, is that correct?

Comment: you can use ajax, no need for submit

Comment: How would I go about using ajax? Could you give me an example of how that might be done?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

In the change() handler for the accordion, I would send the index of the current accordion section to the server via an AJAX call:

```
$( "#AccordionID" ).accordion({
    change: function(event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'urlToPhpScript.php',
            data:'function=setAccordion&selectedAccordionSection='+ $("#AccordionID").accordion('option', 'active')
        });
    }
});
```

On the server side I would store this value in the users session:

```
<?php
// urlToPhpScript.php
session_start();

if($_GET['function']=='getAccordion') {
    if(isset($_SESSION['currentAccordion'])) {
        return $_SESSION['currentAccordion'];
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

if($_POST['function']=='setAccordion') {
    $_SESSION['currentAccordion'] = $_POST['AccordionID'];  
}
```

Then on each page load I would send an AJAX call to the server that would query the accordion section from the users session:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'urlToPhpScript.php',
        data: 'function=getAccordion',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#AccordionID').accordion('activate', data);
        }
    });
});
```

This way it wouldn't matter how you're navigating from one page to the next, and you wouldn't need to worry about burying a 'currentAccordion' type hidden field on each page of your site.

Comment: This sounds elegant. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'm putting together a simple code sample to go along with the answer.

Comment: I've edited my question above, do you have any thoughts why it isn't working? (There is a bit of wordpress code in there..just letting you so know you don't get confused)

Comment: Just to let you know I ended up storing it in a cookie and I am getting the value via ajax fine, its just the setting of the accordion inside the ajax call that isn't working and I don't know why.

Comment: Something else. I commented all the accordion code out except for the active option and now the accordion doesn't work at all. is it too late to initialize the accordion by the time that ajax call executes?